# A interesting property of symmetric densities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, inverse

Let $f(y)=f(-y)$ be a probability density function and furthermore let $f_0(y)=f(y-u)$ and $f_1(y)=f(y-v)$ be two densities based on $f(y)$ and $l(y)=\frac{f_1(y)}{f_0(y)}$ be the likelihood function. Prove that

$$\frac{l^{-1}(a)+l^{-1}(1/a)}{2}=l^{-1}(1)\quad \forall a$$

I am stuck at this point and would appreciate your help. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

$1-$ $u$ and $v$ are some numbers

$2-$ $l^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $l$

$3-$ $f(y)$ is chosen such that $l^{-1}$ exists.

$4-$ $y\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Are $u$ and $v$ fixed? What do you mean with $l^{-1}$?

Comment: @Avitus yes $u$ and $v$ are some fixed real numbers and $l^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $l$

Comment: I am not sure whether $l^{-1}$ always exists. Is there any necessary condition on $f$ s.t. $l$ is invertible? I tried your formula for $f$ density of a $N(0,1)$ random variable with $u=0$ and $v=1$ and it works.

Comment: @Avitus i edited the question with the necessary information. I think it should be okay now.

Comment: @Avitus A sufficient condition is that $f(y)$ is a monotone decreasing function on $\mathbb R^+$ which makes the result straightforward to prove (the log likelihood ratio becomes an odd function of $y$).

Comment: @DilipSarwate so you mean monotone decreasing in $\mathbb{R}^+$ and increasing in $\mathbb{R}^-$?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Since the density is given to be an even function (or am I mistaken about this?) then monotone decreasing in $\mathbb R^+$ means monotone increasing on $R^-$. Maybe I should have said this explicitly.

Comment: @DilipSarwate No it is clear. You are right. I only wanted to be sure that you were not defining the densities only on the positive real axis. So this means $f$ hast to be monotone decreasing in $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $l$ is increasing and else it is not increasing.

Comment: @DilipSarwate "which makes the result straightforward to prove". please write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(y)$ is a density function that is an even function of $y$, that is, $f(y) = f(-y)$ 
for all $y$.

Let $\mu$ denote a real number and suppose that 
$v = -\mu$ and $u = +\mu$ so that the likelihood ratio is
$$L(y) = \frac{f_1(y)}{f_0(y)} = \frac{f(y-\mu)}{f(y+\mu)}.$$
The likelihood ratio has the following properties:

- $L(0) = 1$
- $\displaystyle L(-y) =  \frac{f(-y-\mu)}{f(-y+\mu)} 
  = \frac{f(y+\mu)}{f(y-\mu)} = \frac{1}{L(y)}$

Thus, for each positive real number $a$ such that there exists
a $y$ with the property that $L(y) = a$, it is true that
$L(-y) = a^{-1}$. The values $+y$ and $-y$ at which $L(\cdot)$ takes
on values $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are symmetrically spaced about $0$,
the mean of $\mu$ and $-\mu$. It is not claimed that there is a
unique $y$ such that $L(y) = a$, but rather that if the set
$\{y \colon L(y) = a\}$ is non-empty, then there is a
one-to-one correspondence between the sets $\{y \colon L(y) = a\}$
and $\{y \colon L(y) = a^{-1}\}$ where the values paired in the
one-to-one correspondence are negatives of each other.

With minor modifications, this argument can be used to show
that for arbitrary $u$ and $v$, the likelihood ratio has values
$a$ and $a^{-1}$ at arguments $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
$\alpha + \beta = u+v$.

My earlier comment about needing $f(y)$ being strictly monotone decreasing
on $\mathbb R^+$ is not quite enough to make the likelihood function
be a strictly monotone function with range $(0, \infty)$ so
that $L^{-1}(a)$ is uniquely defined for all $a > 0$. For example,
if $f(y) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|y|}$, then, with $\mu > 0$,
 $L(y) = \frac{e^{-|y-\mu|}}{e^{-|y+\mu|}}$
has range $[e^{-2\mu},e^{2\mu}]$ with $L(y) = e^{2\mu}$ for all $y \in [\mu,\infty)$
and $L(y) = e^{-2\mu}$ for all $y \in (-\infty,-\mu]$.

---

**Note added in response to OP's comment:**

If $L(y) = \frac{f(y-u)}{f(y-v)}$ where $v$ is not necessarily $-u$, 
then $L(y)$ has the following properties:

- $\displaystyle L\left(\frac{u+v}{2}\right) 
  = \frac{f\left(\frac{u+v}{2}-u\right)}{f\left(\frac{u+v}{2}-v\right)}
  = \frac{f\left(\frac{v-u}{2}\right)}{f\left(\frac{u-v}{2}\right)} = 1$
- $\displaystyle L\left(\frac{u+v}{2}-y\right) 
  =  \frac{f\left(\frac{u+v}{2}-y-u\right)}{f\left(\frac{u+v}{2}-y-v\right)} 
  = \frac{f\left(\frac{v-u}{2}-y\right)}{f\left(\frac{u-v}{2}-y\right)}  
  = \frac{f\left(y+\frac{u-v}{2}\right)}{f\left(y+\frac{v-u}{2}\right)}
  = \frac{f\left(\frac{u+v}{2}+y-v\right)}{f\left(\frac{u+v}{2}+y-u\right)}
  = \frac{1}{L\left(\frac{u+v}{2}+y\right)}.$
  The rest of the argument applies *mutatis mutandis*.

Comment: For $\mu$ it is also no problem for me. I need a proof for $u$ and $v$ starting from the given densities and ending with the expression given.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I included the proof for arbitrary $u$ and $v$ in my answer.